# Прошу, исправь мою всю душу... Нужна ли запятая после "прошу"

Tags: пунктуация

Прошу, исправь мою всю душу...

Answer (score 3):

***Прошу, исправь мою всю душу...***

Запятая ставится.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП) с изъяснительными отношениями. Простые предложения в составе БСП являются односоставными определенно-личными (без подлежащего)

Обычно изъяснительные  отношения обозначаются двоеточием, но допускается использовать **запятую** в предложениях простой конструкции.

**Розенталь:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150

Примечание. При отсутствии оттенка предупреждения в начале бессоюзного сложного предложения данного типа после первой части вместо двоеточия ставится запятая: Слышу, земля задрожала (Н.).

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, она разделяет две основы.

*(Я) прошу, (ты) исправь...*